# How to read a parquet file into a PCollection from s3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-beam, parquet

My problem is simple: I want to read a parquet file from s3 into a PCollection in Apache Beam using the Python Sdk.

I know of the `apache_beam.io.parquetio` module but this one does not seem to be able to read from s3 directly (or does it?).

I know of the `apache_beam.io.aws.s3io` module but this one seems to return an s3 file object or something that is not a PCollection anyway (or does it?).

So what’s the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

if you install beam with the aws requirement

`pip install 'apache-beam[aws]'`

You can just pass in an s3 filename to read from it

```
filename = "s3://bucket-name/...
beam.io.ReadFromParquet(filenam)
```